# Rewrite some URLs that does not end with slash and start with a some specif words

Tags: regex, apache, url-rewriting

Actually I do this with PHP, but I want to do this on Apache level (.htaccess)

I want to make a 301 redirect on urls that start with: *noticias|analises|meteorologia|artigos|videos* and not end with slash or .html

I want to redirect to a page with slash.

Redirect in these cases:

```
/noticias  --> /noticias/
/noticias/soja --> /noticias/soja
/noticias/soja/pag-2 --> /noticias/soja/pag-2/
```

But not in this case:

```
/noticias/soja/1105-soja-opera-em-alta.html
```

Please, someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Just put this in the directory's `.htaccess` file:

```
# noticias/
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://www.example.com/noticias/ [r=301,nc]
```

Or for the second directory:

```
# noticias/soja/
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://www.example.com/noticias/soja/ [r=301,nc]
```

and for the third directory:

```
# noticias/soja/pag-2/
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://www.example.com/noticias/soja/pag-2/ [r=301,nc]
```

Comment: Thank you Adam, but "/noticias" or "/noticias/soja" already are a rewrite rule, I just want to force a slash at the end. Like:
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/\b(noticias|analises|meteorologia|artigos|videos|educacional).*?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]`
But in this cond, this not verify if it already end with slash or .html